# Hibernate tools DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy .<init>() Exception

Tags: hibernate

i configured a project to revese engeenering a database. I can run the process and get some results.

[image]

To change some data i build a "DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy" class

```
package defaultPackage;

...imports

public class MyReverseEngineeringStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy{

    public MyReverseEngineeringStrategy(ReverseEngineeringStrategy delegate) {
        super(delegate);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

.....
}
```

But if i run the same configuration with setted "reveng. strategy:" i run into an error
[image]

[image]

I tried som versions of hibernate
Remove meaven repo directory to force download

pom dependencies

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

How to fix that?

Comment: looks like it is missing no args contructor.

Comment: Yes there ist no constructor without args because i have to use superclass "DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy" and there is no constructor without args. What i do in code is exactly what i find in many tutorials. With my old windows installation this was fine without any problems.

Comment: I know nothing about any tutorials as service provider you are using requires no args constructor.

Comment: OK i try to explain! i cant have a No args constructor If i use a superclass that doesnt have a No args constructor. I know what you mean, but my Problem ist Not that the No args constructor is Missing. I think without any knowing about hibernate  Framework you cant Help me with that Problem, i need a Framework Specialized answere.

Comment: Let me explain - you have to have no arg constructor.

Comment: And I think you need some basic java knowledge as this statement *i cant have a No args constructor If i use a superclass that doesnt have a No args constructor* is false.

Comment: In my last post I tried to say nicely that the answer is useless. That I am absolutely clear about the meaning of the exception! Furthermore, the statement that everything has already worked should make it clear to you that that is not the problem. But if you think that it is still the problem, I suggest you either take a look [HERE Chapter 6.3](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html) or try it yourself. To protect my time, I will no longer enter into the pure exception because, as mentioned, I am aware of this meaning.

Comment: Exception is still there. And you still need a no args ctor implementation :)